# How to drop array items using Lodash.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

As i'm trying to drop the first 5 items in the array when array item cross beyond 10. As my array keeps on adding the items in the setInterval method.

```
function checkArray(array,limit,toshow){
    var length =  array.length;
    if(length > limit){
        var  splicedArry =  _.drop(array1,toshow);
        array = splicedArry;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fekkyDev/6q7pnh4v/29/)

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: `_.drop` creates a new array, so you are adding items to one array but then returning a different one. You should either use the return value or mutate the original one.

Comment: A simple question, when array length is for example 20 what you expect ? drop the first 5 only ? keep the last 5 only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the entire working code from your JSfiddle (using Vanilla JS):

```
var arrayEl = [];
var count =0;

setInterval(function(){
  count = ++count;
  arrayEl.push(count);


},1000)

setInterval(function() {
  // modify array by reference
  checkArray(arrayEl,10,5)
  // print the contents of modified array
  console.log(arrayEl)
}, 1100)


function checkArray(array,limit,toshow){
  // splice takes 2 arguments to modify an array (people often confuse it with `slice`
  if (array.length > limit) array.splice(0, toshow);
}
```

Lodash `_.drop` creates a new array, so the entire code code would look like this:

```
var arrayEl = [];
var count =0;

setInterval(function(){
  count = ++count;
  arrayEl.push(count);


},1000)

setInterval(function() {
  // you must assign the returned value to your original array
  arrayEl = checkArray(arrayEl,10,5)
  console.log(arrayEl)
}, 1100)


function checkArray(array,limit,toshow){
  if (array.length > limit) return _.drop(array, toshow);

  return array;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it's better to provide an explanation as well and not just codes. :)

Comment: How to do in lodash?

Comment: @fekkyDev added the example using lodash

Answer (score 3):

You could use vanilla js:

```
let checkArray = (array, limit, toShow) => {
  if (array.length > limit) array.splice(toShow);
}
```

Comment: this will mutate array, consider using slice or _.drop from lodash

Comment: @givehug But that's the goal, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using lodash `_.drop()` method, you better use JavaScript's native **[`Array#splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**, it takes as params the index from which to remove and the number of items to be removed.

So in your function you will call it like this:

```
array.splice(0, toshow)
```

So it removes the first `toshow` elements from the `array`, where `toshow` is the number of items to be removed.

This is how should be your function:

```
function checkArray(array, limit, toshow) {
  if (array.length > limit) {
    array.splice(0, toshow);
  }
  return array;
}
```

**Demo:**

This is your code updated with the right function:

```js
var arrayEl = [];
var count = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  count = ++count;
  arrayEl.push(count);


}, 1000)
setInterval(function() {


  console.log(checkArray(arrayEl, 10, 5))



}, 1100);

function checkArray(array, limit, toshow) {
  if (array.length > limit) {
    array.splice(0, toshow);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `lodash` use `_.dropRight`
**For Example**

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

function checkArray(array,limit,toshow){
    var length =  array.length;
    if(length > limit){
        return _.dropRight(array,(length-toshow));

    }else{
        return array;
    }
}
console.log(checkArray(arr,3,3))
```

Comment: Why use `_.dropRight`? It's the same method as `_.drop` with the only difference is that it removes the items from the end, rather than from the beginning. OP explicitly wants to remove from the beginning, also, `length-toshow` does not do what OP wants - the intent is to drop a specific number of items from the array, using this maths, the number of dropped items depends on the length of the array. I would agree that `toshow` is probably not named correctly but changing how it functions to match the name disregards the original intention.

Comment: sorry.. i thought he/she wants to show only element that are `toshow`